# Add a non-breaking space between moderator name and diamond in comments

Tags: bug, comments, design

[image: freehand circles ftw]

The diamond should be in the same line as moderator's name. Adding a non-breaking space after the name, and removing `margin-left: 3px;` CSS rule from `.mod-flair` fixes that.

Reproduced in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

On [this particular comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263092/disallow-languages-other-than-english-in-chat/263146#comment59756_263092) it happens only when logged in, because

> the space reserved for the comment vote and flag buttons reduces the width of the comment text column by a few pixels. Those buttons are not present if you're not logged in, leaving a bit more room for the comments themselves. Carefully tweaking the comment text length (or column width) using the dev tools can still trigger it.

(as pointed out in comments by Ilmari Karonen)

Comment: What browser are you using? I cannot reproduce this on Firefox, and there's already an `a.comment-user { white-space: nowrap }` CSS rule that *should* prevent this from happening on any browser. I suspect this may be a browser bug.

Comment: What OS? Looks like you're on mobile, android to be exact, based on the red diamond color.

Comment: @ShadowWizard No, I'm on desktop and my OS is Linux Mint.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I'm using Chrome.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed reproducible on Chrome/Chromium. The reason it only happens for [that particular comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263092/disallow-languages-other-than-english-in-chat/263146#comment59756_263092) when logged in is simply because the space reserved for the comment vote and flag buttons reduces the width of the comment text column by a few pixels. Those buttons are not present if you're not logged in, leaving a bit more room for the comments themselves. Carefully tweaking the comment text length (or column width) using the dev tools can still trigger it.